# Creating custom and reusable user interface control

Tags: matlab, user-controls

In some GUI of my own I have created many controls (using [`uicontrol`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html)) to allow users configuring a filter used during later processing stage.

The filter edition consist in a combobox to select the filter type, plus many editboxes that update upon selected filter type and many callbacks to react upon user inputs.

I now need to add this filter selection in another GUI, and, of course, I don't want to copy-paste all the logic I have already done and would prefer to create some custom control that I can reuse as easily as:

```
 filterEditor = uifilter('Parent', gcf);
 set(filterEditor, 'FilterDescription', 'Cylinder (r = 45 cm, h = 1 m)');
 set(filterEditor, 'Callback', @onFilterEditModified);
```

Is there a standard procedure to create custom "`uicontrol`" objects ? I searched the internet and matlab's documentation but did not find any good pointer yet ...

Currently I'm thinking to create custom class deriving from [`hgsetget`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsetget.html):

```
classdef uifilter < hgsetget

    properties
        % Local properties
        FilterDescription;
        Callback;   
    end

    properties(SetAccess=private, GetAccess=private)
        % Internal controls
        globalContainer;
        comboFilterType;
        edit1;
    end

    methods
        function [this] = uifilter(varargin)

            % Create a global `uicontainer` to hold my controls
            [localPVpairs, genericPVpairs] = separatePVpairs(varargin{:});
            this.container = uicontainer(genericPVpairs{:});

            % Create my own controls and logic
            this.comboFilterType = uicontrol('Parent', this.container, ...);
            this.edit1 = ...

        end
    end

end
```

in order to mimic `uicontrol` behavior (`set`, `get`, `findobj`, etc...) but maybe there's more standard approach or some base class other than [`hgsetget`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsetget.html) to start from (i.e. some base class with `Visible`, `Enable`, `HitTest` etc... already defined with default implementation)?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the right approach.

To do it properly, you'll probably need to implement your own `set` and `get` methods for each `uicontrol` property. These `set` and `get` methods will mostly just pass through values to and from the underlying `uicontrol`. You can probably get away without implementing some of the less-used properties in your first draft (e.g. `FontAngle`), adding them in as necessary and just living with the `uicontrol` defaults until then.

In some cases though, they'll need to do more, and you'll need to exercise a bit of care when you implement things such as `set` for the `Parent` property (it may need to destroy the original uicontrol and create a new one for the new parent). You'll also need to exercise care when implementing `set` for the `Position` and `Units` properties - for normal `uicontrol`s they interact in quite a complicated way, and I think the outcome can sometimes depend on which is set first.

I'd also suggest that for the internal properties, as well as setting them to `private`, you might also set them to `Hidden`, to prevent users from trying to meddle with them.

One last point - I think, from some of your other questions, that you're making use of GUI Layout Toolbox. I haven't thought it through much, but you might need to think ahead about whether you need to do anything special to enable that.

Comment: Thank for your support about my many GUI questions :) ... You're right, I need to take care for children of the GUI-Layout type (+bugs introduced in version for HG2 with Visible/Enable properties, see my comments from December 22nd and 23rd 2014 on [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox) ... I'll start to design some `uicontrolbase` base-class and post it here for reference ... I hope MathWorks will also provide us with better way to design advanced/modern GUI in next Matlab releases, cause currently it's quite a mess to do simple things :)

Comment: They're doing exactly that - check out this [Tech Preview](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48142-app-designer) of the planned "App Designer", which I'm guessing is an upcoming replacement for GUIDE. It has loads of sweet new controls, and generates nice OO GUI code that is **infinitely** better than the current GUIDE code. It's not finished yet, so you have an opportunity to provide your feedback for stuff you'd like to see.

Comment: **Sounds great !** I'll test that asap :)

Comment: NB: After first tests, it's still limited (no automatic sizing or flow positionning like with GUI Layout for instance), but that's appealing. I wrote them long feedback for what I'd like to have. Thank for pointing out this TechPreview :)

Comment: I suspect - although this is just a guess - that the App Designer is part of a wider redesign of the GUI-building capabilities of MATLAB, now that the foundation of HG2 is in place. I would hope that there will be lots more GUI goodies as it gradually comes out - you can see, for example, that there are a bunch of extra widgets in the App Designer such as rockers, gauges and dials. Remember also that GUI Layout Toolbox is developed by MathWorks consultants, and I'm sure they'll take into account it's popularity.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back on the issue, a very simple approach *(equivalent to define a custom class inheriting from `hgsetget` or possibly some `uicontrolbase` class to have default behavior for `Enable`, `Position`, etc...)* is to create a class inheriting from `uiextras.Container` in the [GUI Layout toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox).

Indeed this class is fully equivalent to the idea of having a `uicontrolbase` class. It exposes a protected `UIContainer` property which is the panel in which to put all child elements, so it is very easy to build reusable compound component from it:

```
classdef uimyfilter < uiextras.Container

    %% --- Exposed properties
    % NB: Can be accessed with set/get routines
    properties(Dependent, Transient)
        FilterDescription;
        Callback;
    end
    methods
        {% ... own custom set/get logic for exposed properties ... %}
    end

    %% --- Lifetime
    methods
        function [this] = uimyfilter(varargin)

            % Consume or init local properties from varargin list
            [c, otherPvPairs] = uimyfilter.extractOrInitPvPairs(varargin, { ...
                'FilterDescription', @()'Cylinder (r = 10 cm, h = 42 cm)'; ...
                'Callback', @()[]; ...
            });

            % Call superclass with other pv pairs
            this@uiextras.Container(otherPvPairs{:});

            % Build interface
            grid = uiextras.Grid('Parent', this.UIContainer, 'Spacing', 5, 'Padding', 5);

                c.handles.cbFilterType = uicontrol('Parent', grid, 'Style', 'Popup', 'String', { 'Cylinder', 'Sphere' }, 'Callback', @(s,e)onFilterTypeChanged(this,s,e));
                uiextras.Empty('Parent', grid);

                c.handles.cardFilterParams = uiextras.CardPanel('Parent', grid);
                uiextras.Empty('Parent', grid);

                set(grid, 'ColumnSizes', [90, -1]);
                set(grid, 'RowSizes', [23, -1]);

                uicontrol('Parent', c.handles.cardFilterParams, 'Style', 'Text', 'String', '... todo: params for cylinder ...', 'BackgroundColor', 'r');
                uicontrol('Parent', c.handles.cardFilterParams, 'Style', 'Text', 'String', '... todo: params for sphere ...', 'BackgroundColor', 'r');

            % Store local properties and handles for later calls
            this.state = c;

            % Init Gui
            this.refresh();

        end
    end

    %% --- Internal logic
    methods(Access=private)
        function [] = refresh(this)
            set(this.state.handles.cardFilterParams, 'SelectedChild', get(this.state.handles.cbFilterType, 'Value'));
        end
        function [] = onFilterTypeChanged(this, s, e) %#ok
            this.refresh();
            if (~isempty(this.state.Callback)), 
                this.state.Callback(this); 
            end
        end
    end
    methods(Access = protected)
        function [] = redraw(this) %#ok            
        end
    end
    properties(GetAccess=private, SetAccess=private)
        state;        
    end

    %% --- Helpers
    methods(Static, Access=protected)
        function [c, otherPvPairs] = extractOrInitPvPairs(pvPairs, consumeDescriptor)

            % Check arguments
            if (nargin < 2), 
                error('Not enough input arguments.'); 
            end
            if (~isempty(consumeDescriptor) && ...
                (~iscell(consumeDescriptor) || ~ismatrix(consumeDescriptor) || ...
                ~iscellstr(consumeDescriptor(:, 1)) || ~all(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)isa(x, 'function_handle'), consumeDescriptor(:,2), 'UniformOutput', false)))))
                error('Invalid descriptor for properties to consume.'); 
            end
            if (~iscell(pvPairs) || (~isvector(pvPairs) && ~isempty(pvPairs))  || (length(pvPairs(1:2:end)) ~= length(pvPairs(2:2:end))) || ~iscellstr(pvPairs(1:2:end)))
                error('Invalid list or property names/values pairs.'); 
            end

            % Consume local properties
            c = struct();
            otherNames = pvPairs(1:2:end);
            otherValues = pvPairs(2:2:end);
            for ki = 1:size(consumeDescriptor, 1),
                pname = consumeDescriptor{ki,1};
                pinit = consumeDescriptor{ki,2};
                idx = strcmpi(otherNames, pname);
                if (isempty(idx)),
                    c.(pname) = pinit();                     
                elseif (isscalar(idx)), 
                    c.(pname) = otherValues{idx};
                    otherNames(idx) = []; otherValues(idx) = [];
                else
                    error('Property `%s` appears more than once.', pname);
                end                
            end

            % Recompose other pv
            otherPvPairs = cell(1, 2*length(otherNames));
            otherPvPairs(1:2:end) = otherNames(:);
            otherPvPairs(2:2:end) = otherValues(:);

        end        
    end

end
```

Exposed properties and internal logic is of course fully tied to the compound component to have anyway, building interface is as simple as adding `uicontrol` or `uiextras.(...)` objects to `this.UIContainer`.

PS: For R2014b and later, you have to inherit from `uix.Container` in [GUI Layout toolbox for HG2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox) anyway the idea is similar.